# CS0012 The type 'EventLogEntryType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.8

currently I am using .net standard and .net framework in the project . In .net standard I have created a function

```
public static void WriteEntryLog(string source, string message, EventLogEntryType entryType)
```

when I am trying to use it on .net framework installer class , that time it gives an error

```
Error   CS0012  The type 'EventLogEntryType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. 
You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Diagnostics.EventLog, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
```

if i install the latest nuget package of "System.Diagnostics.EventLog" it got work in compile time but during the installation its unable to find the System.Diagnostics.EventLog package and failed to install.

Answer (score 0):

you mentioned the latest version

> if i install the latest nuget package of "System.Diagnostics.EventLog"

Normally, the Visual Studio creates the assembly binding redirects automatically for you. You can find those binding redirects in the .config files in the project's target directory after build. Those assembly redirects contain the infrmation for the runtime to use the exact version you have included at your project as "latest" when the 4.0.2 is requested by the application.
When you creating the installer it is easy to miss the config file.

You may try either:

1. Ensure you have added all .config files into your installer,
2. Or add the exact nuget package version (4.0.2) from your nuget manager. This would make the binding redirection unnecessary.